# Example of non-uniqueness in ODEs

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, dynamical-systems

I came across a proof that shows using the energy method that the ODE problem

$$ u - \frac{d}{dx}f(u_x) = 0;   \ \ \ \  u(0)=u(1) = 0 $$

has a unique solution if $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$  is monotone increasing.

The notation here means

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(u_x) = f'(u_x)\cdot u_{xx} $$

e.g. if $f(x) = -x$, then $\frac{d}{dx}f(u_x)=-u_{xx}$

I couldn't find a decreasing function $f$ that shows that there might not be a unique solution. Is there any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

$u+u_{xx}/\pi^2=0$ has the solutions $u^{(1)}=0$ and $u^{(2)}=\sin(\pi x)$

Basically your attempt almost worked but you need to scale $f$.

(In fact, for almost all scalings of $f$ the solution *is* unique, as you'll learn in any course on PDE)